# Web Service Client utilizando Axis 2

Tags: java, webservice, eclipse, wsdl, axis

Estoy queriendo generar un Web Service Client, con Java utilizando Eclipse, a partir de un WSDL ya creado. Pero al querer finalizar la creación me aparece el siguiente mensaje:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el detalle aparece lo siguiente:

```
Exception occurred during code generation for WSDL  : javax.xml.stream.FactoryConfigurationError: Requested factory com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxOutputFactory cannot be located.  Classloader
=org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.ContextFinder@1a09bb4
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jst.ws.axis2.consumption.core.command.Axis2ClientCodegenCommand.execute(Axis2ClientCodegenCommand.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.core.fragment.CommandFragmentEngine.runCommand(CommandFragmentEngine.java:419)
    at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.core.fragment.CommandFragmentEngine.visitTop(CommandFragmentEngine.java:359)
    at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.core.fragment.CommandFragmentEngine.moveForwardToNextStop(CommandFragmentEngine.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.SimpleCommandEngineManager$6.run(SimpleCommandEngineManager.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.runInCurrentThread(ModalContext.java:466)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:374)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.run(WizardDialog.java:1059)
    at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.SimpleCommandEngineManager.runForwardToNextStop(SimpleCommandEngineManager.java:264)
    at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.WizardPageManager.runForwardToNextStop(WizardPageManager.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.WizardPageManager.performFinish(WizardPageManager.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.DynamicWizard.performFinish(DynamicWizard.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.finishPressed(WizardDialog.java:853)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.buttonPressed(WizardDialog.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog$2.widgetSelected(Dialog.java:619)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4353)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4172)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3761)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:832)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:808)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler$New.executeHandler(WizardHandler.java:269)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler.execute(WizardHandler.java:290)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor100.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:247)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.execute(HandlerServiceHandler.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:508)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:210)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.LegacyHandlerService.executeCommand(LegacyHandlerService.java:343)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.actions.CommandAction.runWithEvent(CommandAction.java:159)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:420)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4353)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4172)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3761)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1151)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
    Caused by: javax.xml.stream.FactoryConfigurationError: Requested factory com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxOutputFactory cannot be located.  Classloader =org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.ContextFinder@1a09bb4
    at javax.xml.stream.FactoryLocator.loadFactory(FactoryLocator.java:120)
    at javax.xml.stream.FactoryLocator.locate(FactoryLocator.java:109)
    at javax.xml.stream.FactoryLocator.locate(FactoryLocator.java:54)
    at javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory.newInstance(XMLOutputFactory.java:29)
    at org.apache.axis2.util.PolicyUtil.policyComponentToString(PolicyUtil.java:188)
    at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.emitter.AxisServiceBasedMultiLanguageEmitter.getInputElement(AxisServiceBasedMultiLanguageEmitter.java:2824)
    at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.emitter.AxisServiceBasedMultiLanguageEmitter.generateMethodElement(AxisServiceBasedMultiLanguageEmitter.java:2358)
    at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.emitter.AxisServiceBasedMultiLanguageEmitter.loadOperations(AxisServiceBasedMultiLanguageEmitter.java:2242)
    at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.emitter.AxisServiceBasedMultiLanguageEmitter.createDOMDocumentForCallbackHandler(AxisServiceBasedMultiLanguageEmitter.java:1232)
    at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.emitter.AxisServiceBasedMultiLanguageEmitter.writeCallBackHandlers(AxisServiceBasedMultiLanguageEmitter.java:1198)
    at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.emitter.AxisServiceBasedMultiLanguageEmitter.emitStub(AxisServiceBasedMultiLanguageEmitter.java:500)
    at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationEngine.generate(CodeGenerationEngine.java:283)
    ... 73 more
```

Busqué muchisimo en la web pero no pude encontrar una solución. Agradecería si alguien tiene noción de que se trata.

Comment: Buenas tardes, es mejor que proporcione directamente el mensaje que arroja el sistema en lugar de una imagen, muchas gracias

Comment: Agregué el detalle del mensaje, la imagen coloqué porque pensé que era más visible de esa manera

Comment: Sugeriria que bajara la herramienta de axis directamente y la manipulara por comandos mediante el wsdl4java https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/download.html, en este link sugieren una respuesta para el complemento de fuse https://developer.jboss.org/thread/246577

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31583581/requested-factory-com-ctc-wstx-stax-wstxoutputfactory-cannot-be-located/33231364

Comment: @Lcop eso hice, descargué directamente el axis2 desde su sitio web y lo coloqué en una ubicación de mi disco C. En la carpeta bin del axis no se encuentra la herramienta wsdl4java, sino la wsdl2java

Comment: @SJuan76 ya probé con el jar que propone la solución, pero sigue dando el mismo error

Comment: @Carlos si me equivoque al referenciar el ejecutable es el que indicas, trate de usar el wsdl2java para generar el codigo fuente java, despues solo sera moverlo a eclipse y compilar

Comment: @Lcop disculpame que sea molestoso, en linea de comando tendría que colocar wsdl2java, seguido por la dirección de mi archivo WSDL, es así? Lo hice pero me salió el siguiente warning: log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.axis2.i18n.Project
ResourceBundle).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Usage: WSDL2Java [options] -uri <url or path> : A url or path to a WSDL

Comment: Wsdl2java -url archivo.wsdl

Comment: @Lcop Me pide lo siguiente: log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly. Ubico el archivo log4j.properties en la dirección %AXIS_HOME%/conf/ . No se si debo colocarlo en otra ubicación o si debo agregar unas líneas al archivo

Comment: @carlos Puedes ignorar lo del log4j, sólo es un warning y no una excepción por lo que no afecta mayormente la ejecución.

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, el problema no es de tener Axis (que lo tienes porque si no ni arrancaba el wizard de Eclipse). Te falta el [stax](/questions/tagged/stax) parser en el proyecto ([fuente](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6327262/requested-factory-com-ctc-wstx-stax-wstxinputfactory-cannot-be-located)).

Lo puedes [descargar](https://github.com/FasterXML/woodstox/releases) y añadirlo al classpath o incluirlo como dependencia maven

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.woodstox</groupId>
    <artifactId>woodstox-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```